# Incorrect Number of Days Displayed in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uikit

In the CalendarCollectionLayout, I have set the item size to be a fraction of the width (1/7th for seven days). Despite this, the calendar is not displaying the days of the week correctly.

I have tried adjusting the layout settings in CalendarCollectionLayout, but the issue still persists. The calendar does not show all seven days in a week as expected. Here's an example of the current display: [insert an image or detailed description of the current output].

Can anyone help me identify what might be going wrong in my layout configuration or elsewhere in my code that is causing this issue?

```
struct CalendarCollectionLayout {
    func create() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? {
        let itemFractionalSize: CGFloat = 1.0 / 7.0
        
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(itemFractionalSize), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(itemFractionalSize))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(itemFractionalSize))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        group.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 3, trailing: 0)
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 16, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
        
        return section
    }
}

class CalendarDateFormatter {

    private let calendar = Calendar.current
    private let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    private var nowCalendarDate = Date()
    private(set) var days = [String]() //쓰기 수준이 private이라는 뜻. 읽기는 in
    
    init() { 
        self.configureCalendar()
    }
    
    func getYearMonthText() -> String {
        let yearMonthText = self.dateFormatter.string(from: self.nowCalendarDate)
        return yearMonthText
    }
    
    func updateCurrentMonthDays() {
        self.days.removeAll()
        
        let startDayOfWeek = self.getStartingDayOfWeek()
        let totalDayOfMonth = startDayOfWeek + self.getEndDateOfMonth()
        
        for day in 0..<totalDayOfMonth {
            if day < startDayOfWeek {
                self.days.append("")
            } else {
                self.days.append("\(day - startDayOfWeek + 1)")
            }
        }
    }

}

private extension CalendarDateFormatter {
    
    func getStartingDayOfWeek() -> Int {
        return self.calendar.component(.weekday, from: self.nowCalendarDate) - 1
    } 
    
    func getEndDateOfMonth() -> Int {
        return self.calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: self.nowCalendarDate)?.count ?? 0
    } 
    
    func configureCalendar() {
        let components = self.calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Date()) 
        self.nowCalendarDate = self.calendar.date(from: components) ?? Date()
        self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy년 MM월" 
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Your question misses the URL here: "[insert an image or detailed description of the current output]." Have you missed to insert it?